# display svg into pdf file in angular

Tags: html, angular, pdf, svg, jspdf

i'm trying to add svg content into my pdf  , i have tried

```
    var svgContent = '<svg width="100" height="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" /></svg>';
    var svgData = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svgContent);
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.addImage(svgData, 'JPEG', 10, 20, 20, 20);
```

but it's not adding into my pdf file

Comment: You're missing the SVG namespace on the SVG root element.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add the SVG namespace as the Robert's comment suggests. Secondly you are using the wrong method to put the SVG directly onto the PDF. According to the docs the proper way to do this is to use `addSvgAsImage`:
https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-svg.html

Pay attention that this is an asynchronous method so instead of `doc.addImage(...)` you may want to use:

```js
await doc.addSvgAsImage(svgContent, 10, 10, 100, 100);
```

If you want to use the `addImage` method you can still do it but you'll have to put the SVG on the canvas first:

```js
const svgContent = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100">' +
  '<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />' +
'</svg>';

const svgData = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svgContent);
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = 100;

const doc = new jsPDF();
const img = new Image();

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

img.onload = function() {
  canvas.getContext('2d')!.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'), 'JPEG', 10, 10, 100, 100);
};

img.src = svgData;
```